# ifstream.open() not opening file

Tags: c++, file, istream

I've been having a nightmare this evening trying to get some very simple I/O functionality going. As embarrassing as it is, I've had some great help from people on here!

My current issue is that I'm attempting to use ifstream.open() and it simply is not opening the file. This is confirmed by getline(ifstream,line); returning false on it's first call.

Here is a copy paste of the current code:

```
std::string FSXController::readLine(int offset, FileLookupFlag flag)
{
    // Storage Buffer
    string line;
    streampos sPos(offset);

    try
    {
        // Init stream
        if (!m_ifs.is_open())
            m_ifs.open("C:\\Users\\guyth\\Documents\\test.txt", fstream::in);
    }
    catch (int errorCode)
    {
        showException(errorCode);
        return "";
    }

    // Set stream to read input line
    m_ifs.seekg(sPos);
    if (!getline(m_ifs, line))
        return "";

    // Close stream if no multiple selection required
    if (flag == FileLookupFlag::single)
        m_ifs.close();

    return line;

}
```

This code is in 'bug fix mode' and so therefore is pretty messy, don't worry too much about that, cleanup will happen when this method is finally working.

I have tried:

- Absolute file path
- Saving path into string and then calling the .c_str() method.
- Running VS 2015 in Administrator mode
- Ensuring file has read/wright access
- Ensuring no duplicate file extensions
- Yes the file definitely has content! :D

I'm kinda out of ideas now and am really not sure why this file is refusing to load.

The condition: `if (!getline(m_ifs, line))` Repeatedly returns true... :(

EDIT: I've just tried checking `m_ifs.fail()` immediately after the open and it returns true, so we know the fail flag was triggered :/

Thanks

Guy

Comment: Why is it embarrassing that *you've had some great help from people on here*? :) :)

Comment: Why not use my answer on your other Q?

Comment: @RSahu - Embarrassing that I needed to ask for help on something that is typically trivial, but the help itself was certainly nothing be be embarrassed about :)

Comment: perhaps the offset is greater than the file length

Comment: @robor78 - this could actually have been the case with my second 'test' text file, however the fail flag is being triggered on the line below the ifstream.open() command.

Answer (score 6):

Enable exceptions before opening the stream:

```
m_ifs.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
```

Otherwise `m_ifs.open` won't throw.

And you have to catch `std::ifstream::failure`:

```
  try {
    m_ifs.open("C:\\Users\\guyth\\Documents\\test.txt", fstream::in);
  }
  catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception opening file: " << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
  }
```

See [`ios::exceptions`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @RustyX. Without wishing to sound like a total noob... how do I view that std::cerr output? I'm running a win32 application with no console. (It's on the todo list)

Comment: `MessageBox(NULL, std::strerror(errno), "MyApp", 0);`. If that doesn't help, you can use Windows' own error message using `GetLastError` and `FormatMessage`. Note: you have to read `errno` as soon as the error occurs. Next I/O will reset it.